# Java 8: Is it possible to assign a method reference to a variable?

Tags: java

I Googled for an answer to this question but couldn't find one.

In Java 8, I know this is possible:

```
// someMethod is defined as: someMethod(AFunctionalInterface i)
someMethod(someObject::someOtherMethod);
```

Question is: is it possible to do the following

```
AFunctionalInterface i = anObject::SomeMethod;
```

Also, is it possible to assign a lambda to a variable and pass it around, like so?

`Printer f = () -> System.out.println(..); methodThatTakesPrinter(f);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, according to an example cited in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2):

> ```
> Task t = () -> System.out.println("hi");
> Runnable r = t::invoke;
> ```

In addition, the following is stated:

> A method reference expression is compatible in an *assignment context* [emphasis mine], invocation context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a functional interface type (§9.8) and the expression is congruent with the function type of the ground target type derived from T.

Comment: So I should be able to do this? `Interface f = () -> System.out.println("hi"); anObject.doStuff(1, f);`

Comment: @Prog That's a non-sequitur. Where does `someone` get declared? What is its type? How is `Interface` declared? You can clearly assign a `() -> void` to a variable declared as an interface that is declared with a single method, `void thisCanBeAnyName();`. I've asked a follow-up question on this, which is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25776804/1424875).

Comment: A clearer example: `Printer f = () -> System.out.println(..); methodThatTakesPrinter(f);` Is this possible?

Comment: @Prog Yes, if `Printer` is declared as `interface Printer{ public void someNameThatDoesntNeedToMatchInOrderToWork();}`. The interface has to be *congruent* with the lambda or method reference signature (see the JLS I linked for a formal statement on this).

Comment: But a lambda has no signature, apart from parameters. So in the case above, the lambda simply must not have any arguments, like the method defined in the Printer interface?

Comment: @Prog Yes, that is correct. If it takes no arguments, then the interface's declaration for a method must also not take any arguments.