# In Java, is an expression assignable to a declared variable iff. it can be passed as a parameter declared with the same type?

Tags: java, variable-assignment, jls

<sub>This question was inspired by [Java 8: Is it possible to assign a method reference to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776595/java-8-is-it-possible-to-assign-a-method-reference-to-a-variable/25776672#25776595).</sub>

As I currently understand (which may not be completely right), the invocation of, say `fooMethod(FooType ft)` as `fooMethod(myFooInstance)` causes an implicit assignment of `myFooInstance` to a local variable within `fooMethod`'s body, whose name is `ft`, and whose type is declared as `FooType`. Clearly, in this case, I could also assign `myFooInstance` to a field or local variable whose type is `FooType`, for instance, in a class with a declared field `private FooType fooField`, using `this.fooField = myFooInstance;`.

However, scanning JLS 8.4.1, there is no mention of assignment when dealing with method parameters. JLS 5.3 similarly does not mention assignability, at least with an initial reading of that section.

So, are rules for variable typing and use the same in both strict invocation, and assignment contexts? (or, does is a value assignable to a method parameter *if and only if* it is assignable to a field/local variable with the same declaration?)

(the same declaration implies a field/local/parameter that is not final, and visibility/accessibility of fields is not considered for the purposes of this question)

**Edit:**

`FooType` is not necessarily a concrete class, but a tool of phrasing my question. It could be a functional interface, plain-old-interface, proxy class, primitive, etc.

To rephrase a bit clearly, is there a value (or return value of a function call/language construct that returns a value), that can be assigned to:

```
FooType ft;
```

or passed to

```
myMethod(FooType ft){ ...
```

*but not both* for *some* choice of type for FooType (which would act as a counterexample and make the answer "no").

Comment: Including a small demonstration case, instead of merely explaining it, would be good.

Comment: @user2864740 I'm looking to find the existence or non-existence of such a situation in which assignability to a variable doesn't imply ability to pass that value to a method instead, or vice versa. I do not have a concrete example, as my question itself is seeking to find if one exists or not.

Comment: I think you should clarify further what you're asking.  Even if the code isn't syntactically correct, you should show what it is you are asking for.  I can see two or three different (very different) things you are implying, and I'm not sure what your real question is.  Section 15.12.4.5 of the JLS talks about Activation Frames and copying parameter values, if that's all you are looking for.

Comment: @markspace I'm asking one specific thing (worded a few logically-equivalent ways), namely, whether a value that I can pass as a parameter is one I can *always* assign to a variable of the same type, and vice-versa.

Comment: You would need to compare [5.2 Assignment Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) and [5.3 Method Invocation Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) for differences. I can't see any that are relevant.

Comment: @EJP I'll try to take a look at that tomorrow, as it's a bit late over here. If you'd like to contribute answer with that, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: The old JLS, (or maybe the JVM spec, it's been a while) referred to parameter types as "assignable" -- a parm passed as a type X must meet the requirements to be "assignable" to a variable of type X.  I suppose that some twist in generics or some such may have introduced a loophole in that rule, but the basic principle holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to compare [5.2 Assignment Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) and [5.3 Method Invocation Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) for differences. I can't see any that are relevant.